# Issue in creation a chart in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I recently use pentaho BA 8 and I have a problem in the creation of a new chart with sql query in Pentaho.

I've made a query and assign that in the chart, but in the moment to see the preview view, the view appear in blank. FYI, the chart is correctly associated to a row in the layout structure.

My question is, the result of query must be assigned manually in the chart's axis?

The sql query is:

```
select sum(cantidad) as cantidad, id_cliente from viewdetallecaja where ptl_id = ${ptl}
```

and the values in the chart properties is attached
[Pentaho's chart properties area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqBOy.png)

Answer (score 0):

can you please add details as to what kind of chart you assigned to. Also check catalina.out which is the log file for Pentaho's BI and paste any errors here if any.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the results of the query (Query3) to the chart in the Datasource property. Double check that the query is actually returning results.